# How to kill a zombie process which always initiated whenever geany does

Tags: zombie-process, geany

I am using Geany for editing a large text data in Ubuntu (600MB or so). But after a while, a zombie process starts whenever I start Geany and it couldn't load the file so that I edit the content. It took 100% of my CPU while Geany runs. I try to kill the zombie process with the following:

```
    kill -HUP `ps -A -ostat,ppid,pid,cmd | grep -e '^[Zz]' | awk '{print $2}'`
```

But once I start the application again, the zombie process starts automatically. Also tried logout.

What can I do to kill the zombie process once and for all? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't kill a zombie process *since it's already dead*.

> On Unix and Unix-like computer operating systems, a zombie process or
>   defunct process is a process that has completed execution (via the
>   exit system call) but still has an entry in the process table: it is a
>   process in the "Terminated state".

(from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process))

It's simply an entry in the process table with no associated process. It exists because the *spawning* (parent) process has yet to collect the return status (via `wait()`). Other than that it will consume no resources.

So I suspect the parent process is either busy or not working properly. I would first of all try to identify that process (via the `PPID` column in `ps`, for example)

EDIT: I note there's a [geany issue raised/resolved](http://sourceforge.net/p/geany/bugs/804/) around this

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. I come across that bug report you sent me. Although I couldn't get to fix using the solution specified, I truncate the large file into small pieces of files, and access it from there. Thanks for your help!